# Retrieving and modifying XGBoost weights

Tags: python, xgboost

I am using `xgboost` library to train a binary classifier. I would like to prevent data leakage from trained algorithm by adding noise to the weights (e.g. values at the leaf nodes of trees in the ensemble). For that I need to retrieve weights for each tree and modify them.

I can see the weights by using `dump_model` or `trees_to_dataframe` on the Booster object, which I define as

```
model = xgb.Booster(params, [dtrain])
```

The latter method returns a Pandas dataframe

```
   Tree  Node    ID                          Feature  Split   Yes    No Missing        Gain     Cover
0      0     0   0-0                           tenure   17.0   0-1   0-2     0-1  671.161072  1595.500
1      0     1   0-1      InternetService_Fiber optic    1.0   0-3   0-4     0-3  343.489227   621.125
2      0     2   0-2      InternetService_Fiber optic    1.0   0-5   0-6     0-5  293.603149   974.375
3      0     3   0-3                           tenure    4.0   0-7   0-8     0-7   95.604340   333.750
4      0     4   0-4                     TotalCharges  120.0   0-9  0-10     0-9   27.897919   287.375
5      0     5   0-5                Contract_Two year    1.0  0-11  0-12    0-11   32.057739   512.625
6      0     6   0-6                           tenure   60.0  0-13  0-14    0-13  120.693176   461.750
7      0     7   0-7  TechSupport_No internet service    1.0  0-15  0-16    0-15   37.326447   149.750
8      0     8   0-8  TechSupport_No internet service    1.0  0-17  0-18    0-17   34.968536   184.000
9      0     9   0-9                  TechSupport_Yes    1.0  0-19  0-20    0-19    0.766754    65.500
10     0    10  0-10                MultipleLines_Yes    1.0  0-21  0-22    0-21   19.335510   221.875
11     0    11  0-11                 PhoneService_Yes    1.0  0-23  0-24    0-23   19.035950   281.125
12     0    12  0-12                             Leaf    NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   -0.191398   231.500
13     0    13  0-13   PaymentMethod_Electronic check    1.0  0-25  0-26    0-25   43.379410   320.875
14     0    14  0-14                Contract_Two year    1.0  0-27  0-28    0-27   13.401367   140.875
15     0    15  0-15                             Leaf    NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN    0.050262    94.500
16     0    16  0-16                             Leaf    NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   -0.052444    55.250
17     0    17  0-17                             Leaf    NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   -0.058929   111.000
18     0    18  0-18                             Leaf    NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   -0.148649    73.000
19     0    19  0-19                             Leaf    NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN    0.161464    63.875
```

where leaf values are stored in column *Gain* (leaf nodes are those that have value *Leaf* in column *Feature*). Hence I could add noise to the respective rows in the *Gain* column, however I then do not know how to convert the Pandas dataframe back to the Booster object/XGBoost model. How should I go about achieving this? Or is there some other and better way for retrieving and modifying  XGBoost leaf nodes' values?

Answer (score 2):

if you use the `dump_model` method, you should be able to edit the text file, then load it back into python like this:

```
bst = xgb.Booster({'nthread': 4})  # init model
bst.load_model('model.bin')  # load data
```

from: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_intro.html

That said, adding noise won't eliminate a data leakage problem and may or may not even help, so I'd just double-check whether you have a better option available to your use case like re-training another model on the proper input data.

Comment: After dumping model cannot be read from file. load_model method could read only save_model results